# How to make this particular type of box?

Tags: tables, boxes

I need this type of command. Someone can help me? I do this with tabular and some negative space  but it is very difficult to work like this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Furthermore, it would be a good idea to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), containing what you have done so far and how you have achieved what is mentioned in the question. Furthermore, it might be important to know if this box is going to contain only corollaries (i.e., math) or there will be text as well.

Comment: Andrea, do you just need to input text in it or also equations/graphs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would create a `\newcommand` in Tikz.

**Edit**: I raised the line and the text node a bit so it's not too crowded. Also, the line is back to the default thickness (better looking).

Now you can change the colour of the node and the line, so the arguments are:

1. The word that goes in the top-left corner.
2. Colour
3. The longer text itself.

I didn't manage to write the equation you have in your example, I don't know the proper syntax, but I thought it was not critical since your question was about the special box.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\newcommand{\mytab}[3]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=text, text=#2] (#1) {\raisebox{1mm}{\textbf{\emph{#1}}}};  
        \node[anchor=text,text width=\textwidth] (sec) {\hphantom{\textbf{\emph{#1}}} \hspace{.2em} #3};
        \draw[draw=#2] (#1.north east|-sec.north) -- ($(#1.south east)+(0,2pt)$) -- ($(#1.south west)+(0,2pt)$) -- 
                    (sec.south west) -- (sec.south east) -- (sec.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}       
}

\begin{document}

    \mytab{a}{green}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper dui in tellus hendrerit semper. Aenean in rutrum nulla. Nullam eleifend feugiat neque, sit amet iaculis arcu aliquam id. Vestibulum maximus, risus at condimentum tempus, ipsum nunc suscipit velit, at tempus nisi arcu nec ipsum. Morbi eget tortor in turpis ultricies condimentum. Sed venenatis condimentum feugiat. Integer eget ligula sem. Sed gravida laoreet ultrices. Vivamus tincidunt ac metus nec finibus. Praesent a felis sed enim mollis ornare.}

    \mytab{Text}{blue}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper dui in tellus hendrerit semper. Aenean in rutrum nulla. Nullam eleifend feugiat neque, sit amet iaculis arcu aliquam id. Vestibulum maximus, risus at condimentum tempus, ipsum nunc suscipit velit, at tempus nisi arcu nec ipsum. Morbi eget tortor in turpis ultricies condimentum. Sed venenatis condimentum feugiat. Integer eget ligula sem. Sed gravida laoreet ultrices. Vivamus tincidunt ac metus nec finibus. Praesent a felis sed enim mollis ornare.}

    \mytab{Very Long Text}{red}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper dui in tellus hendrerit semper. Aenean in rutrum nulla. Nullam eleifend feugiat neque, sit amet iaculis arcu aliquam id. Vestibulum maximus, risus at condimentum tempus, ipsum nunc suscipit velit, at tempus nisi arcu nec ipsum. Morbi eget tortor in turpis ultricies condimentum. Sed venenatis condimentum feugiat. Integer eget ligula sem. Sed gravida laoreet ultrices. Vivamus tincidunt ac metus nec finibus. Praesent a felis sed enim mollis ornare.}

    \mytab{Corollario}{purple}{Sia ($X,T$) spazio topologico.\\
        Equation goes here
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are a Genius man!  I have the last trouble..  I need to put  the first argument  in normal font with   \emph{ \textbf{  } }   and be able to decide his colour  i.e.  \colour{ \emph{ \textbf{  } }  }    and at last to change his vertical position  with  \raisebox{.07cm  } {     }    and so ...

raisebox{.07cm  } {  \colour{ \emph{ \textbf{  } }  }     }      


in few words i need to personalise your  PERFECT command with my own style used in the example!      


Thank you!

Comment: @AndreaLeo Color both `text` and the line?

Comment: Yes the text in the first arg. For what concerns the line I  understand how to change color  @Aleanno

Comment: @AndreaLeo See changes. You can change both with one command.

Comment: Yeah! That's it! I love you <3

Comment: @azetina Nice catch. The inner sep will change the draw so I cannot add it, but if I add your command changing to `\linewidth-25pt` it fits within the frame. Why using `ex` in raisebox?

Comment: `ex` is the normal measurment for height of an `x` so that if you scale fonts then it will scale accordingly, while `em` is for horizontal lengths. `25pt` is a bit too big.

Comment: @azetina Ah I didn't know that. Yes, it's big but it's the least to fit within the margin.

Comment: Using `\columnwidth` would be a bit safer since `\textwidth` will not have the correct value in a multi-column setting.  Also, I think I would set this up as an environment.

Comment: @A.Ellett Oh why an environment? Are there advantages to it? I'll test `\columnwidth`. :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that it *should be* an environment.  I merely meant to say that my choice would have been to create an environment.  My choice would have also been to create key words for the header and color.  But these are, I believe, matters of personal taste.  However, the matter of `\columnwidth` is more about how the construct, whether a macro or environment, functions in different set ups for the page.  :)

Comment: @A.Ellett  Don't worry! I appreciate the input! I was just wondering why you would have chosen an environment. Just personal taste or some reasons behind it? It's good to know new info. :D