# Draw a box with tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm trying to draw something like the following:

[image]

but with my following ( note that i'm tired with `tcolorbox`)

**Code :**

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\tcbset{
    lemmastyle/.style={enhanced, colback=white, colframe=black, arc=0pt, 
                       fonttitle=\bfseries, description color=Maroon,  
                       colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black,    
                       top=\tcboxedtitleheight,
                       boxed title style={arc=0pt},
                       attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                }%
                      },
}

\newtcbtheorem{myLemma1}{Question :}{lemmastyle}{thm}


\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth, enhanced,  valign=center, colback=white, colframe=black, sharp corners, shadow={0pt}{0pt}{0mm}{black},boxrule=0.5pt]
\textbf{Question 1~: Area of the region bounded by the curves $y=x^2+2, y=-x, x=0$ and $x=1$ is}
\[  \dfrac{7}{10} \]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth, enhanced,  valign=center, colback=white, colframe=black, sharp corners, shadow={0pt}{0pt}{0mm}{black},boxrule=0.5pt]
\textbf{Question 2~:}
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\textbf{ Area of the region bounded by the curves $y=x^2+2, y=-x, x=0$ and $x=1$ is \[ \dfrac{7}{10}\] }
\end{myLemma1}

\end{document}
```

I got this

**output:**

[image]

- Could someone please show me how to set up a `tcolorbox` environment to get the box I want?

Comment: Apparently, you want to have the text `Area of the region...` right to the framed title box?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  yeah, if possible .

Comment: Difficult, I think, at least using it this way :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Danke vielmals for ur effort, so for each question  i will to use my code to set it manually

Comment: @Educ Would [something like this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245162/4778) do it for you?

Comment: @Alenanno This is this is useful but i prefer working with 'tcolorbox' than 'Tikz' for creating box

Comment: @Educ Gotcha! :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like this (but be careful not to add a \par at the begin, as this will remove the effect of the hangindent):

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\tcbset{
    lemmastyle/.style={enhanced, colback=white, colframe=black, arc=0pt,
                       fonttitle=\bfseries, description color=Maroon,
                       colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black,
                       top=\tcboxedtitleheight,
                       boxed title style={arc=0pt},
                       before title=\strut,
                       attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/1},
                       before upper={\vspace{\dimexpr-\tcboxedtitleheight+\dp\strutbox-0.8pt}\par\hangindent\tcboxedtitlewidth\hangafter-2},                       
                      },
}

\newtcbtheorem{myLemma1}{Question :}{lemmastyle}{thm}

\begin{document}

\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\lipsum*[1]
\end{myLemma1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a problem with this solution, if inside myLemma1 I write "something", then add a tasks environment, and write "stuff", the "stuff" has a huge indentation. Like so: https://i.imgur.com/Zszlyjf.jpg

Answer (score 7):

Warning: Awful hack ahead ;-)

It's difficult to align the running text and the attached title box -- perhaps there are some options in `tcolorbox` manual, but I did not found it.

Since the attached title box itself is a `tcolorbox`, most (all?) settings to this can be done the same way like for the outer box.

I've used however a separate `\newtcolorbox` -- it's not the `tcbtheorem` any longer, to provide for more flexibility (Using the `xparse` facilities of `tcolorbox` would improve this even more)

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{myinternallemma}[2][]{%
  enhanced,
  title={\phantom{Some}},
  detach title,
  attach title to upper={\hskip0.2\textwidth},
  description color=Maroon,  
  top=-5pt,
  colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black,    
  boxed title style={%
    enhanced,arc=0pt,
    bottomtitle=1pt,
    boxrule=1pt,
    coltitle=black,
    lowerbox=ignored,
    size=normal,
    sharp corners,
    width={0.1\textwidth},
    fonttitle={\bfseries},
    title={Question \thetcbcounter},
    attach title to upper={},
    box align=bottom,
  },%
  attach boxed title to top left={%
    yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight,
  },
  #1
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{myinternallemma}{}
  \textbf{ Area of the region bounded by the curves $y=x^2+2, y=-x, x=0$ and $x=1$ is \[ \dfrac{7}{10}\]} \blindtext
\end{myinternallemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Educ: ;-) Please consider to accept Ulrike Fischer's solution. Her answer is clearer and easier!

Comment: okay as you want :)