# Draw a special box with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, tikz-styles

By inspiring from that nice code of that [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245132/how-to-make-this-particular-type-of-box/245162#245162) 
I would like to draw something like that

[image]

but with my tired i just could draw this

**Output:**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\newcommand{\mytab}[3]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=text, text=#2] (#1) {\raisebox{1mm}{\textbf{\emph{#1}}}};  
        \node[anchor=text,text width=\textwidth] (sec) {\hphantom{\textbf{\emph{#1}}} \hspace{.2em} #3};
        \draw[draw=#2] (#1.north east|-sec.north) -- ($(#1.south east)+(0,2pt)$) -- ($(#1.south west)+(0,2pt)$) -- 
                    (sec.south west) -- (sec.south east) -- (sec.north east);

                \draw[draw=#2] (#1.south east|-sec.north) -- ($(#1.south east)+(0,2pt)$) -- ($(#1.south west)+(0,2pt)$) -- 
                    (sec.north west) -- (sec.north east) -- (sec.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}       
}

\begin{document}

    \mytab{a}{green}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper dui in tellus hendrerit semper. Aenean in rutrum nulla. Nullam eleifend feugiat neque, sit amet iaculis arcu aliquam id. Vestibulum maximus, risus at condimentum tempus, ipsum nunc suscipit velit, at tempus nisi arcu nec ipsum. Morbi eget tortor in turpis ultricies condimentum. Sed venenatis condimentum feugiat. Integer eget ligula sem. Sed gravida laoreet ultrices. Vivamus tincidunt ac metus nec finibus. Praesent a felis sed enim mollis ornare.}

    \mytab{Text}{blue}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper dui in tellus hendrerit semper. Aenean in rutrum nulla. Nullam eleifend feugiat neque, sit amet iaculis arcu aliquam id. Vestibulum maximus, risus at condimentum tempus, ipsum nunc suscipit velit, at tempus nisi arcu nec ipsum. Morbi eget tortor in turpis ultricies condimentum. Sed venenatis condimentum feugiat. Integer eget ligula sem. Sed gravida laoreet ultrices. Vivamus tincidunt ac metus nec finibus. Praesent a felis sed enim mollis ornare.}

    \mytab{Very Long Text}{red}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper dui in tellus hendrerit semper. Aenean in rutrum nulla. Nullam eleifend feugiat neque, sit amet iaculis arcu aliquam id. Vestibulum maximus, risus at condimentum tempus, ipsum nunc suscipit velit, at tempus nisi arcu nec ipsum. Morbi eget tortor in turpis ultricies condimentum. Sed venenatis condimentum feugiat. Integer eget ligula sem. Sed gravida laoreet ultrices. Vivamus tincidunt ac metus nec finibus. Praesent a felis sed enim mollis ornare.}

    \mytab{Corollario}{purple}{Sia ($X,T$) spazio topologico.\\
        Equation goes here
    }
\end{document}
```

- also i would like to add counter to title, would you help me with that Please

Comment: You might also enjoy the wheels that are invented previously `tcolorbox`, `mdframed` and so on.

Comment: would you give me link to see that wheels in tcolorbox and mdframed

Comment: Search this site, or have a look at the manuals: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mdframed/mdframed.pdf

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate? I mean, you could have asked a comment below my answer.

Comment: i asked new question since needs add counter to title + different style

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While someone else is working into a `tcolorbox` solution (which I also think is better than this one) you can use Alenanno's code with an extra `--cycle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\newcounter{mytabcounter}
\newcommand{\mytab}[3]{
\addtocounter{mytabcounter}{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=text, text=#2] (#1) {\raisebox{1mm}{\textbf{\emph{#1: \themytabcounter}}}};  
        \node[anchor=text,text width=\textwidth] (sec)
        {\hphantom{\textbf{\emph{#1: \themytabcounter}}} \hspace{.2em} #3};
        \draw[draw=#2] (#1.north east|-sec.north) -- ($(#1.south east)+(0,2pt)$) -- 
           ($(#1.south west)+(0,2pt)$) -- (sec.south west) -- 
           (sec.south east) -- (sec.north east)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}       
}

\begin{document}

    \mytab{a}{green}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper dui in tellus hendrerit semper. Aenean in rutrum nulla. Nullam eleifend feugiat neque, sit amet iaculis arcu aliquam id. Vestibulum maximus, risus at condimentum tempus, ipsum nunc suscipit velit, at tempus nisi arcu nec ipsum. Morbi eget tortor in turpis ultricies condimentum. Sed venenatis condimentum feugiat. Integer eget ligula sem. Sed gravida laoreet ultrices. Vivamus tincidunt ac metus nec finibus. Praesent a felis sed enim mollis ornare.}

    \mytab{Text}{blue}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper dui in tellus hendrerit semper. Aenean in rutrum nulla. Nullam eleifend feugiat neque, sit amet iaculis arcu aliquam id. Vestibulum maximus, risus at condimentum tempus, ipsum nunc suscipit velit, at tempus nisi arcu nec ipsum. Morbi eget tortor in turpis ultricies condimentum. Sed venenatis condimentum feugiat. Integer eget ligula sem. Sed gravida laoreet ultrices. Vivamus tincidunt ac metus nec finibus. Praesent a felis sed enim mollis ornare.}

    \mytab{Very Long Text}{red}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper dui in tellus hendrerit semper. Aenean in rutrum nulla. Nullam eleifend feugiat neque, sit amet iaculis arcu aliquam id. Vestibulum maximus, risus at condimentum tempus, ipsum nunc suscipit velit, at tempus nisi arcu nec ipsum. Morbi eget tortor in turpis ultricies condimentum. Sed venenatis condimentum feugiat. Integer eget ligula sem. Sed gravida laoreet ultrices. Vivamus tincidunt ac metus nec finibus. Praesent a felis sed enim mollis ornare.}

    \mytab{Corollario}{purple}{Sia ($X,T$) spazio topologico.\\
        Equation goes here
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, yeah let's wait for  t⊗t⊗tcolorbox  solution btw you forget to add counter

Comment: Could you add the counter to title  please

Comment: @Educ: counter added.

Comment: Fixed my name :P

Comment: @Alenanno: Ups! Excuse me.

Comment: @Ignasi No problem! Everybody mistakes it lol

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to produce a `tcolorbox` solution which I think is a better tool than `TiKZ` for this problem. But as it was not mentioned by OP, I prefer to write an independent answer instead of editing my previous answer which really addressed the original problem. If someone thinks I should just add it in my previous answer, just let me know.

Following code declares a `tcolorbox` called `mytctab` with two parameters, the first one is the box name and the second the frame color. An optional parameter can be used as shown in last example. This boxes have their own counter which is automatically added after title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{mytctab}[3][]{%
enhanced,
breakable,
size=small,
sharp corners,
colback=white,
colbacktitle=white,
fonttitle=\bfseries\itshape,
coltitle=#3,
colframe=#3,
title=\strut#2:~\thetcbcounter,
boxed title style={size=small, colframe=white},
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight*7/10},
before upper=\hspace{\tcboxedtitlewidth},
frame hidden,
overlay={\draw[#3] (frame.south west)--(title.south west)-|
   (title.north east|-frame.north)-|(frame.south east)--cycle;},
#1
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{mytctab}{a}{green}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mytctab}

\begin{mytctab}{Text}{blue}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mytctab}

\begin{mytctab}{Very Long Text}{red}
\lipsum[3]
\end{mytctab}

\begin{mytctab}[colback=purple!20]{Corollario}{purple}
Sia ($X,T$) spazio topologico.\\
\[\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1\]
\end{mytctab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks you so i ll accept your first answer since i mentioned only `Tikz` but with `tcolorbox` useful too

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ignasi's first (excellent) answer, I am posting my own variation of it which I altered for my own purposes. The major changes are these

- I have turned the `\mytab` *command* into an *environment*. This allows rather more freedom in what can be typeset (see the example below with `\obeylines`).
- I use the `mytabounter` counter to name the `sec` nodes -- Ti*k*Z does not like accented characters as labels.
- I have somewhat altered the drawing of the outline to simplify changes and reduce space at the top of the frame.
- I've put the label text into an `\sbox` to streamline things somewhat.
- The typeset box now sits precisely inside the `\textwidth`.
- The `rounded corners` are purely decorative and can be omitted.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcounter{mytabcounter}
\newsavebox{\secbox}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytab}{mm}{%
    \stepcounter{mytabcounter}
    \sbox{\secbox}{\textcolor{#2}{\textbf{\large\strut\emph{#1: \themytabcounter}}}}
    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
        \node[anchor=text] (sec-\themytabcounter) {\raisebox{1pt}{\usebox{\secbox}}};  
        \node[anchor=text,
            text width=\textwidth-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-2*\pgflinewidth] (sec)
        \bgroup
            \baselineskip1.4em %% See below *
            \hphantom{\usebox{\secbox}}%
            \hspace{0.75em}
            \ignorespaces
}{%
        \par
        \egroup;
        \draw[draw=#2,rounded corners=2pt] 
            %% * The 3pt can be altered to adjust for a change in \baselineskip
            ($(sec-\themytabcounter.south west)+(0,3pt)$)coordinate(Y) -- 
            (sec.south west) -- 
            (sec.south east) -- 
            %% Change the -3pt as needed to reduce space at the top of the box
            ($(sec.north east |- sec-\themytabcounter.north east) + (0,-3pt)$) --
            ($(sec-\themytabcounter.north east) + (0,-3pt)$) --
            (sec-\themytabcounter.north east |- Y) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{mytab}{a}{green!75!black}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper dui in tellus hendrerit semper. Aenean in rutrum nulla. Nullam eleifend feugiat neque, sit amet iaculis arcu aliquam id. Vestibulum maximus, risus at condimentum tempus, ipsum nunc suscipit velit, at tempus nisi arcu nec ipsum. Morbi eget tortor in turpis ultricies condimentum. Sed venenatis condimentum feugiat. Integer eget ligula sem. Sed gravida laoreet ultrices. Vivamus tincidunt ac metus nec finibus. Praesent a felis sed enim mollis ornare.


    \begingroup
    \obeylines
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    \endgroup
    \end{mytab}

    \begin{mytab}{Text}{blue}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper dui in tellus hendrerit semper. Aenean in rutrum nulla. Nullam eleifend feugiat neque, sit amet iaculis arcu aliquam id. Vestibulum maximus, risus at condimentum tempus, ipsum nunc suscipit velit, at tempus nisi arcu nec ipsum. Morbi eget tortor in turpis ultricies condimentum. Sed venenatis condimentum feugiat. Integer eget ligula sem. Sed gravida laoreet ultrices. Vivamus tincidunt ac metus nec finibus. Praesent a felis sed enim mollis ornare.       \end{mytab}

    \begin{mytab}{Very Long Text}{red}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper dui in tellus hendrerit semper. Aenean in rutrum nulla. Nullam eleifend feugiat neque, sit amet iaculis arcu aliquam id. Vestibulum maximus, risus at condimentum tempus, ipsum nunc suscipit velit, at tempus nisi arcu nec ipsum. Morbi eget tortor in turpis ultricies condimentum. Sed venenatis condimentum feugiat. Integer eget ligula sem. Sed gravida laoreet ultrices. Vivamus tincidunt ac metus nec finibus. Praesent a felis sed enim mollis ornare.       \end{mytab}

    \begin{mytab}{Corollario}{purple}
        Sia ($X,T$) spazio topologico.\\
        Equation goes here
    \end{mytab}

\end{document}
```

[image]